# Deceived by car salesman

Tags: loans

I thought I was a co signer for my daughter to help build her credit but she is not on the loan  I founded out a year later She is upset, faithfully pays the note and gets  no credit for it.  I did not have a job how could that happen  and what can I do because the salesman trick us and told me after a year she could have my name taken off but now she is not on the car what could we do about this deception

Comment: Whereabouts in the world are you located? This may be more of a legal question and the treatment of such things depends on where you live.

Answer (score 8):

The only thing that is important here is the *documentation* you and your daughter signed. If that documentation states that you were a co-signer and that your daughter was the primary on the loan, and then if the loan is not being reported in your daughter's name, you have a cause for action. If, however, the documentation says the loan is entirely in your name, the mistake is *yours*. Even in that case, though, your daughter may be able to take over the loan, or she may be able to take out a loan from a separate institution and use that to pay off the current loan. Obviously, this may be difficult if she does not have a credit history, which is what got you here in the first place. :(

Comment: Yes my mistake for believing lies they told us. She is not on the loan at all but is paying for the loan thinking her name is on the loan with mine I don't know how they gave me a loan  with no job. I would never gotten that car if I had a job something my daughter was trying to purchase and I  failed her and myself by not knowing what was happening. Now she have 5 years to pay for a car she's not getting credit for if the dealership don't come up with something to make good on a bad deal.

Comment: @ElainePatton - did you confirm by looking at the actual documents you signed? If you can't find it, both the dealership and the bank who currently owns the loan should be able to give you a copy. As ChrisInEdmonton suggested, look at the document and see what it says.

Answer (score 1):

At this point there is not much you can do.  The documentation probably points to you being the sole owner and signer on the loan.  Then, any civil suit will degenerate into a "he said, she said" scenario.  Luckily, no one was truly harmed in the scenario.

Obtaining financing through a car dealer is almost always not advisable.  So from here, you can do what should have been done in the first place.  Go to banks and credit unions so your daughter can refinance the car.  You will probably get a lower rate, and there is seldom a fee.

I would start with the bank/CU where she does her checking or has some other kind of a relationship.  If that fails, anywhere you can actually sit and talk with a loan officer is preferable over the big corporate type banks.

Car dealers lying is nothing new, it happens to everyone.  Buying a car is like a battle.